# Docker rabbitmq image error when building "Unable to perform operation on node"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, dockerfile, rabbitmqctl

I am having an error when trying to build image with:

`docker-compose build`

Error:

[image: Error]

docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    container_name: hrabbitmq
    image: hyperloopupv:rabbitmq
    build: './rabbitmq'    
    ports:
    - "5672:5672"
    - "15672:15672"
    hostname: hypernode
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - rabbit1:/var/lib/rabbitmq
      - ./conf/:/etc/rabbitmq/
    command:  bash -c "sleep 10; rabbitmq-server;"
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_USERNAME=guest
      - RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=guest
      - RABBITMQ_NODE_NAME=rabbit@hypernode
```

Rabbitmq dockerfile:

```
FROM rabbitmq:3-management

MAINTAINER victorcf999@gmail.com

# APT update, wget and sudo
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install apt-utils -y
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN apt-get install sudo -y
RUN apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates -y

#Rabbitmq status
RUN rabbitmqctl status

#Set user
RUN rabbitmqctl add_user hyper hyperpass
RUN rabbitmqctl set_user_tags hyper administrator
RUN rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / hyper ".*" ".*" ".*"

#Eneable management console
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
RUN sudo chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq/

WORKDIR ~

# Expose ports.
EXPOSE 5672 15672
```

The error says that the node is not running, but I have not seen anything about starting a node in the documentation. In all the tutorial I looked at this should work.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I did not found the error, I made it other way.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.6.6-management

MAINTAINER victorcf999@gmail.com

ADD rabbitmq.config /etc/rabbitmq/

RUN chown rabbitmq:rabbitmq /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
CMD ["rabbitmq-server"]
```

rabbitmq.config:

```
[
  {rabbit,
    [
        {default_vhost,<<"/">>},
        {default_user,<<"hyper">>},
        {default_pass,<<"hyperpass">>},
        {default_permissions, [<<".*">>, <<".*">>, <<".*">>]},
        {default_user_tags, [administrator]}
    ]
  },
  {rabbitmq_management,
    [{listener, [{port, 15672}]},
        {http_log_dir, "/var/log/rabbitmq/management_http.log"}]
  }
].
```

I hope this helps you